# R - tidyverse - mutate function to reduce a dataframe length

Tags: r, count, tidyverse

I learn R and the tidyverse and I can not find an answer to my question because I lack the proper vocabulary to describe what I want to achieve.

I have a large dataset with that structure :
`df <- tibble(x = c("species1", "species2", "species1", "species3"), y = 1:4)`

and I need to "compress" it into that modified dataframe by adding the observations for each unique species

`df_modif <- tibble(x = c("species1", "species2", "species3"), y = c(4,2,4))`

Could someone help me by explaining if there is a way to achieve this, please? And is there a word to describe that "compression" of a dataframe?

Have a nice day

Comment: `df %>% count(x, wt = y, name = 'y')` or `df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(y = sum(y))`

Comment: Thank you very much. So, it is the function wt or summarise that are needed.

Comment: `mutate` does not change number of rows. `summarize` does change the number of rows, usually returning 1 row per group (though that's a little flexible in recent dplyr versions.)